# Yii2 basic Swift_TransportException from command

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

When I want to send a email with command in terminal I get Swift_TransportException:

> Expected response code 220 but got an empty response in
>   AbstractSmtpTransport.php:445

I've created SendEmailController class in commands dir and method in that class:

```
public function actionSend() {            
    Yii::$app->mailer->compose()->setFrom('fromsomeone@gmail.com')
    ->setTo('tosomeone@yahoo.com')    
    ->setSubject('Test Subject from command')    
    ->setTextBody('Test Body')    
    ->send();                                        
}
```

I have the same method in the SiteController and when I call over the url, it works.
What's the difference between command and url in this case?
Did anyone have the same problem?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you got the same mailer config in web and console?

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check your console config, mailer settings must be same as in web config

Comment: That's it! I did not have a mailer config in the console. Thank you !